# Why does Pythagoras theorem work while adding RMS values of the sum of two functions?

Tags: statistics, functions

Why does the root mean square value of a function like $f(x)=a\ cosx +b$ which is obtained by [image]

and gives $\sqrt{a^2/2+b^2}$ exactly matches with the value if we add the RMS of the functions individually by Pythagoras theorem like  $(a/\sqrt{2})^2+b^2$ ?
Does that indicate $a\cos x$ and $b$ are orthogonal?Im totally confused!

Can someone please explain me why Pythagoras theorem work while adding RMS values?

Comment: Yes. It means that the constant function $1$ and $\cos x$ are orthogonal. Calculate their inner product
$$(\cos x,1)=\frac1{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}\cos x\cdot 1\,dx$$ to be sure :-)

Comment: And observe that because the definite integral is additive we get for the mean square
$$(a\cos x+b,a\cos x+b)=a^2(\cos x,\cos x)+2ab(\cos x,1)+b^2(1,1).$$ And the middle term is zero by orthogonality.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen but what eludes me is that....what does the orthogonality two functions mean?And why did you take the limits as 0 to $2\pi$ ? (
BTW i'm just a layman in statistics..so :-P )

Comment: Have you studied general inner product spaces yet? Orthogonality simply means that the inner product vanishes. I used the interval $[0,2\pi]$ to cover a full period. If you use a shorter interval the rule may not hold. For example with $T_1=0$, $T_2=\pi/4$ the functions $\cos x$ and $1$ "point at nearly the same direction" (because they are both positive in this interval), and Pythagoras rule fails to give the correct RMS.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen "Have you studied general inner product yet?"-No,I actually faced this problem while adding RMS currents in AC circuits. I'm not a statistics student(more of a physics student :-P).However I think I got you,we must consider the complete period of a function while integrating the inner product, and that is quite similar to finding the resultant of two vectors(and proving they are orthogonal).Thanks a lot for the help :-)!

Comment: Good! And nice intuition in realizing that some kind of orthogonality is at play here.

Comment: In this context the inner product of f and g is the integral of f(x)g(x) from x=0 to x=2$\pi$.